# JavaScript stack overflows even when no recursive function is present

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, stack-overflow

Suppose we wanted to build big structures by using lambdas as "holes" representing the location where we want to add new data. For example, here we build `[0,[1,[2,null]]]` using that idea:

```
builder_0 = hole => hole;                // hole => hole;
builder_1 = hole => builder_0([0,hole]); // hole => [0, hole];
builder_2 = hole => builder_1([1,hole]); // hole => [0, [1, hole]];
builder_3 = hole => builder_2([2,hole]); // hole => [0, [1, [2, hole]]];

// prints [0,[1,[2,null]]], but will stack overflows if too many lines
console.log(JSON.stringify(builder_3(null)));
```

This works fine. We can also do it in a loop:

```
let builder = hole => hole;
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
  let last_builder = builder;
  builder = hole => last_builder([i, hole]);
};
console.log(builder(null));
```

This works too, but this algorithm will stack overflow if the limit is larger than `10000`. The problem is that, since `last_builder([i,hole])` isn't evaluated inside the `hole => ...` closure, it will build up chunks of unevaluated lambdas that will rapidly consume the whole stack. Note that `[0,[1,[2,null]]]` is just a useless example, JavaScript will fail to build **any** large structure using the hole-based technique above (think of trees, JSONs, immutable containers and so on).

Tail-call optimization and trampolining won't help here, as we don't even have a recursive function to begin with. Is there any clever trick that allows this kind of functional idiom to work without stack overflows?

Comment: Why not push each lambda into the array, instead of having 10,000 nested arrays, each with only an integer and another array?  I don't get the purpose of this data structure.

Comment: Use  a service worker, a promise, and wait for the response.

Comment: @Amy this is to compile a pure functional language which doesn't have mutability. The thing is, sometimes a function will stack overflow even after tail-call optimization. For example: https://gist.github.com/MaiaVictor/b35ddf2b0979aabef5ce995b1fdde73d -- this function, when compiled to JS, will stack overflow even if you remove recursive talls by using TCO. I'm wondering if there is any way to avoid that when I target JS.

Comment: The first two lines of your first snippet are enough to exhibit the issue, when followed by the last line of your first snippet.  With line 2, the builder has been re-defined to call itself *ad infinitum*.  There is no terminal condition to stop the calls.

Comment: @Amy you're wrong; the snippet works fine for small values. The stack overflow happens for the reason I explained: the closure builds chunks of unevaluated function calls.

Comment: @MaiaVictor I don't know why you would tell me *I'm wrong* when I exhibited the issue in my browser console using the lines I indicated.

Comment: @Amy oh, I think I misunderstood your comment. I thought you were talking about the snippet on the Gist. You mean the one on the question. My bad. I've fixed the example.

Comment: Uh, no, I wasn't referring to your gist.  The edits to the question have made my previous comments moot.

Comment: @Amy so, I'm confused, sorry. You're saying that the Gist doesn't terminate? It does, you can run it and it returns a valid result for `n=1000`. It only overflows for larger limits.

Comment: I said "I was not referring to your gist."

Comment: @Amy Jesus, I need glasses. So, yes, you were right that the snippet on my question was wrong. I fixed it to correctly demonstrate the issue. Thanks for pointing the mistake.

Comment: This is a single linked list, i.e. a recursive data structure but with a dynamic NIL case. If you drop the mutation you can build it recursively and use a trampoline. However, why would you need a dynamic NIL case in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

As you're transpiling functional code you can allow yourself not being 'functional' in the JS part. So you can create the data structure that you need without recursion:

```
const builder = (count,hole) => {
   let arr = [hole];
   let i = 0;
   while (count--) arr = [count,arr]
   return arr;
}

console.log(builder(22333,null))
```

(please try it out on the browser's console, as the code snippet tool is not able to reproduce it)

Comment: True! This works in this case, but wouldn't work for more complex algorithms. There are techniques to convert arbitrary recursive functions to a non-functional style, but they require complex global program transformations.

Answer (score 2):

I realized the right way to do it is by trampolining. We just use a direct lambda to wrap the result:

```
builder_0 = hole => () => hole;                // hole => hole;
builder_1 = hole => () => builder_0([0,hole]); // hole => [0, hole];
builder_2 = hole => () => builder_1([1,hole]); // hole => [0, [1, hole]];
builder_3 = hole => () => builder_2([2,hole]); // hole => [0, [1, [2, hole]]];
```

Then we use a `while` loop to peel the layers without blowing the stack:

```
var result = builder(null);
while (typeof result === "function") {
  result = result();
}
```

Here is a complete example that builds a linked list with 100000 numbers:

```
let builder = x => x;
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
  let last_builder = builder;
  builder = x => (() => last_builder([i,x]));
};

var result = builder(null);
while (typeof result === "function") {
  result = result();
}

console.log(result);
```

It doesn't stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recusion with three functions.

```js
const
    identity = value => value,
    structure = (number, value) => [number, value],
    construct = (number, value) => number--
        ? construct(number, structure(number, value))
        : value;
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(construct(1000, null)));
```

Comment: Sadly this will still overflow for large enough nums.

Comment: Breaks with 10k

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is suitable for your needs, but you could run your "lambda composition" calling a reducer on an array with the values you want to insert in your structure.

`Reduce` calls the provided function for each entry in the array, "accumulating" the return in a variable

```js
const build = (last_o,new_v) => [new_v,last_o]
const values = [4,3,2,1,0]
const str = values.reduce(build,null)
console.log('Structure: ',str)
```